# Change Image with multiple languages

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a index.html a javascript file and the XML site.
The multiple XMLs are for the various languages and I want to change the default logo to the different language logo ones.

**The Logo in the Index:**

```
    <img class="loadlogo" src="data/img/lorem_logo_en.png">
```

and now I want to change the Logo path with my javascript.

**I used to change text with:**

```
  $(".exampleclass").html($(xmldoc).find("changebutton").text())
```

I don't want to change it with onclick because I have 10 different languages and with onclick I would need to change by ID.

Could it be similair to my text solution -  like instead of changing text i would need to change the value of src ? The issue I have is the multiple languages, if there would be just 2 I could do onclick.

**Full:**
Index.html

```
<div id="loadly">
    <img class="loadinglogo" src="data/img/lorem_logo_en.png">
    <div class="loadtr">
        <div class="loadingbar"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript snippet:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (getParam('language') != "") {
        lang = (getParam('language'))

    }
    if (window.top != window.self) {
        $('.logo').hide()
    }
    loadxml()
    setHeight()
});

    var langstr = "<div class='menubutton'><a class='langbtn' data-language='de'>DE</a> | <a class='langbtn' data-language='en'>EN</a> | <a class='langbtn' data-language='fr'>FR</a> | <a class='langbtn' data-language='nl'>NL</a> | <a class='langbtn' data-language='pl'>PL</a></div>"

    $('.menubuttons').append(langstr)

    $('.menubutton').click(function() {
        krpano.call("tween(view.hlookat," + $(this).attr('data-lookat') + ",0.9,easeInOutSine);");
        $('#menulayer').removeClass('out');
        $('#menulayer').css('left', '-240px')
        setTimeout(function(id) {

            createInfo(id)

        }, 1000, $(this).attr('data-id'))

    })

    $('.langbtn').click(function() {
        window.location.href = "index.html?language=" + $(this).attr('data-language')
    })
    initAction()

}
```

**reading xml:**

```
var xmldoc





function loadxml(){
    
    $("#xmldaten").load("data/xml/content_"+lang+".xml", "",
    function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

        xmldoc = $.parseXML( responseText );
        
    
        
        initContent()

    })
}

function initContent(){


    initPano()
$("#xmldaten").html("")
}
```

Comment: `$(".loadlogo").attr("src",$(xmldoc).find("something").attr("lang"))`

Comment: Set the language attribute to document when you change the language. Then find the image with that specific language and then update it

Comment: @mplungjan what does attr("lang) stand for ?

Comment: whatever element that has a lang attribute. Change for anything else in the XML that has a "de" or a string that can yield "de" if parsed

Comment: @mplungjan probably my fault but doesnt work for me

Comment: Share your code in a `[<>]` snippet

Comment: for example where do you load your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as replacing

```
if (getParam('language') != "") {
    lang = (getParam('language'))
}
```

with

```
const lang = getParam('language') || "en"; // assuming en is default
$(".loadlogo").attr("src",`data/img/lorem_logo_${lang}.png`)
```

Comment: That will be implemented in the javascript part, right ? What do I modify in the index.html ? because if i put it in my documentreading.js it wont change logo by chosen language.

Comment: It worked now, sorry for the misunderstanding